# Escape username spaces in SCP

Tags: ssh, scp

I've been playing around with SCP for a while, and I've been able to transfer files from one place to another. 
It all worked nicely until I needed to copy a file from Ubuntu to a Windows user who had spaces in his username (* **groan** *)

While I got it working for SSH like this:

```
ssh "User Name Spaces"@192.168.0.42
```

It didn't work with SCP:

```
scp "myfile.txt" "User Name Spaces"@192.168.0.42:folder
```

As it returns:

```
User Name Spaces: invalid user name
```

I've tried all kinds of things:

```
scp "myfile.txt" "User Name Spaces"@192.168.0.42:folder
scp "myfile.txt" "User\ Name\ Spaces"@192.168.0.42:folder
scp "myfile.txt" "User\\ Name\\ Spaces"@192.168.0.42:folder
scp "myfile.txt" "User\\\ Name\\\ Spaces"@192.168.0.42:folder
scp "myfile.txt" "'User Name Spaces'"@192.168.0.42:folder
scp "myfile.txt" "'User\ Name\ Spaces'"@192.168.0.42:folder
scp "myfile.txt" "'User\\ Name\\ Spaces'"@192.168.0.42:folder
scp "myfile.txt" "'User\\\ Name\\\ Spaces'"@192.168.0.42:folder
scp "myfile.txt" "'User Name Spaces'@192.168.0.42":folder
```

And so on... but nothing seems to work

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9425222/scp-on-osx-doesnt-allow-spaces-in-usernames                  It looks like you should be able to replace the spaces with underscores. Have you tried that already?

Comment: Yup, I did try to use underscores instead of spaces (and no quotes), and although it doesn't raise an error I guess it treats it as a different user because when I use the correct password, it fails with "Permission Denied".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [`~/.ssh/config`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/ssh_config.5). It's the per-user configuration file for SSH (and commands based on SSH like `scp` and `sftp`). Create it, if it does not exist, and add:

```
Host 192.168.0.42
    User "User Name Spaces"
```

For example:

```
Host localhost
    User "foo bar"
```

Then:

```
$ scp test.txt  localhost:
foo bar@localhost's password:
```

(I don't actually have a user named `foo bar`, so I couldn't finish the test.)

---

You could also create an alias in `.ssh/config`:

```
Host foo
    Hostname 192.168.0.42
    User "User Name Spaces"
```

Then you can conveniently do:

```
ssh foo
scp file foo:
```

And avoid having to type the whole IP address.

---

An alternative, if you have `tar` available on both ends:

```
tar c myfile.txt | ssh "User Name Spaces"@192.168.0.42 tar x
```

`tar` creates a tar archive, saved to standard output and piped through to SSH, where it becomes the input to `tar x`, which extracts the archive. You can use options like `-C` to change the directory (or do so as a shell command before `tar`: `ssh … 'cd foo; tar x`). You could also use compression and save a bit on network bandwitdh:

```
tar zc myfile.txt | ssh "User Name Spaces"@192.168.0.42 tar zx
```

Comment: I didn't understand exactly how tar and the pipe character work together with ssh, but it sounds like a good idea. Sadly, while testing it, it says something along the lines of "tar isnt recognized as an internal or external command" [Note: tar does work on my side, Ubuntu. I guess it comes from the Windows PC not knowing what to do with the command.]

Comment: Hmm. I assumed you might have installed those utilities along with SSH. No hope of installing `tar` on the Windows system (you can get it from [MSYS2](https://msys2.github.io/) or [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/))?

Comment: No, unfortunetly the windows pc is out of my control =\ (The ssh server is running thanks "Bitvise SSH Server")

Comment: @cavpollo try the update

Comment: Thank you very much @muru ! =D The first option did the trick (Somewhat similar to Andrew's link's accepted answer, but while it wasn't clear enough, it seemed to only apply to OSX)

Comment: @cavpollo Yes, it's the same way. I hadn't noticed the comment. OSX uses [OpenSSH](http://www.openssh.com/), the same implementation Ubuntu uses, so it's applicable here too.

Answer (score 2):

I find the `-o user=` option to be more reliable. It works with spaces and apostrophes. Good to use if the username will be somewhat dynamic.

For example:

- `scp -o user="Your Username" ~/file remote:~/file`
- `scp -o user="O'Neill" remote:~/file ~/file`
- `scp -o user="${USERNAME_FROM_VARIABLE}" remote:~/file ~/file`

Source: https://serverfault.com/questions/955058/scp-with-special-username